# Split multi-page PDFs based on barcode on page till the next unique barcode

Tags: vb.net, pdf, merge, pdfsharp

I have VB.NET code that works for one file so far and it splits that file based on a unique bar code that is on each page to identify it.

Each barcode is one of:

COVERSPLIT
COMPLAINTSPLIT
EXHIBITSPLIT
MILSPLIT
SUMSPLIT

The problem is: say, for instance, the first page has the barcode of COVERSPLIT because it's a coversheet, but the next sheet is also a coversheet but it does *not* have the barcode on it. So when I run my code it's only extracting the sheets with those identified barcodes and leaving off the ones that don't.​

I tried doing this:

```
Imports Bytescout.PDFExtractor
Imports System.Collections
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports System.IO.Path
Class Program


    Friend Shared Sub Main(args As String())



        Dim Dir As String = "G:\Word\Department Folders\Pre-Suit\Drafts-IL\2-IL_AttyReview\2018-09\Reviewed\"
        Dim inputFile As String = Dir & "ZTEST01.SMITH.pdf"
        Dim Unmerged As String = Dir & "unmerged\"

        Dim Path As String = IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(inputFile)
        Dim Extracted As String = Path.Substring(0, 7)

        ' Create Bytescout.PDFExtractor.TextExtractor instance
        Dim extractor As New TextExtractor()

        ' Load sample PDF document
        extractor.LoadDocumentFromFile(inputFile)

        Dim pageCount As Integer = extractor.GetPageCount()

        ' Search each page for a keyword 
        For i As Integer = 0 To pageCount - 1

            If extractor.Find(i, "COVERSPLIT", False) Then

                ' Extract page
                Using splitter As New DocumentSplitter()

                    splitter.OptimizeSplittedDocuments = True

                    Dim pageNumber As Integer = i + 1
                    ' (!) page number in ExtractPage() is 1-based

                    Dim outputfile As String = Unmerged & Extracted & " Cover Sheet " & pageNumber.ToString() & ".pdf"

                    splitter.ExtractPage(inputFile, outputfile, pageNumber)


                    Console.WriteLine("Extracted page " & pageNumber.ToString() & " to file """ & outputfile & """")

                End Using
            End If
        Next

        For i As Integer = 0 To pageCount - 1

            If extractor.Find(i, "COVERSPLIT", False) Then

                ' Extract page
                Using splitter As New DocumentSplitter()

                    splitter.OptimizeSplittedDocuments = True

                    Dim pageNumber As Integer = i + 2
                    ' (!) page number in ExtractPage() is 1-based

                    Dim outputfile As String = Unmerged & Extracted & " Cover Sheet " & pageNumber.ToString() & ".pdf"

                    splitter.ExtractPage(inputFile, outputfile, pageNumber)


                    Console.WriteLine("Extracted page " & pageNumber.ToString() & " to file """ & outputfile & """")

                End Using
            End If
        Next
        For i As Integer = 0 To pageCount - 1

            If extractor.Find(i, "COMPLAINTSPLIT", False) Then

                ' Extract page
                Using splitter As New DocumentSplitter()

                    splitter.OptimizeSplittedDocuments = True

                    Dim pageNumber As Integer = i + 1
                    ' (!) page number in ExtractPage() is 1-based

                    Dim outputfile As String = Unmerged & Extracted & " Complaint " & pageNumber.ToString() & ".pdf"

                    splitter.ExtractPage(inputFile, outputfile, pageNumber)

                    Console.WriteLine("Extracted page " & pageNumber.ToString() & " to file """ & outputfile & """")

                End Using
            End If
        Next

        For i As Integer = 0 To pageCount - 1

            If extractor.Find(i, "COMPLAINTSPLIT", False) Then

                ' Extract page
                Using splitter As New DocumentSplitter()

                    splitter.OptimizeSplittedDocuments = True

                    Dim pageNumber As Integer = i + 2
                    ' (!) page number in ExtractPage() is 1-based

                    Dim outputfile As String = Unmerged & Extracted & " Complaint " & pageNumber.ToString() & ".pdf"

                    splitter.ExtractPage(inputFile, outputfile, pageNumber)

                    Console.WriteLine("Extracted page " & pageNumber.ToString() & " to file """ & outputfile & """")

                End Using
            End If
        Next
        For i As Integer = 0 To pageCount - 1

            If extractor.Find(i, "EXHIBITSPLIT", False) Then

                ' Extract page
                Using splitter As New DocumentSplitter()

                    splitter.OptimizeSplittedDocuments = True

                    Dim pageNumber As Integer = i + 1
                    ' (!) page number in ExtractPage() is 1-based

                    Dim outputfile As String = Unmerged & Extracted & " Exhibit " & pageNumber.ToString() & ".pdf"

                    splitter.ExtractPage(inputFile, outputfile, pageNumber)

                    Console.WriteLine("Extracted page " & pageNumber.ToString() & " to file """ & outputfile & """")

                End Using
            End If
        Next

        For i As Integer = 0 To pageCount - 1

            If extractor.Find(i, "EXHIBITSPLIT", False) Then

                ' Extract page
                Using splitter As New DocumentSplitter()

                    splitter.OptimizeSplittedDocuments = True

                    Dim pageNumber As Integer = i + 2
                    ' (!) page number in ExtractPage() is 1-based

                    Dim outputfile As String = Unmerged & Extracted & " Exhibit " & pageNumber.ToString() & ".pdf"

                    splitter.ExtractPage(inputFile, outputfile, pageNumber)

                    Console.WriteLine("Extracted page " & pageNumber.ToString() & " to file """ & outputfile & """")

                End Using
            End If
        Next
        For i As Integer = 0 To pageCount - 1

            If extractor.Find(i, "MILSPLIT", False) Then

                ' Extract page
                Using splitter As New DocumentSplitter()

                    splitter.OptimizeSplittedDocuments = True

                    Dim pageNumber As Integer = i + 1
                    ' (!) page number in ExtractPage() is 1-based

                    Dim outputfile As String = Unmerged & Extracted & " Military " & pageNumber.ToString() & ".pdf"

                    splitter.ExtractPage(inputFile, outputfile, pageNumber)

                    Console.WriteLine("Extracted page " & pageNumber.ToString() & " to file """ & outputfile & """")

                End Using
            End If
        Next

        For i As Integer = 0 To pageCount - 1

            If extractor.Find(i, "SUMSPLIT", False) Then

                ' Extract page
                Using splitter As New DocumentSplitter()

                    splitter.OptimizeSplittedDocuments = True

                    Dim pageNumber As Integer = i + 1
                    ' (!) page number in ExtractPage() is 1-based

                    Dim outputfile As String = Unmerged & Extracted & " Summons " & pageNumber.ToString() & ".pdf"

                    splitter.ExtractPage(inputFile, outputfile, pageNumber)

                    Console.WriteLine("Extracted page " & pageNumber.ToString() & " to file """ & outputfile & """")

                End Using
            End If
        Next

        For i As Integer = 0 To pageCount - 1

            If extractor.Find(i, "SUMSPLIT", False) Then

                ' Extract page
                Using splitter As New DocumentSplitter()

                    splitter.OptimizeSplittedDocuments = True

                    Dim pageNumber As Integer = i + 2
                    ' (!) page number in ExtractPage() is 1-based

                    Dim outputfile As String = Unmerged & Extracted & " Summons " & pageNumber.ToString() & ".pdf"

                    splitter.ExtractPage(inputFile, outputfile, pageNumber)

                    Console.WriteLine("Extracted page " & pageNumber.ToString() & " to file """ & outputfile & """")

                End Using
            End If
        Next

        ' Cleanup
        extractor.Dispose()

        Console.WriteLine()
        Console.WriteLine("Press any key...")
        Console.ReadKey()

    End Sub
End Class
```

As you can see, I just copied and pasted the same `For i...` loop and just changed Dim pageNumber as Integer i+1 to i +2 to include its secondary page.

The problem with that is that sometimes the page with the unique barcode can have a indeterminate number of pages after it....

So, how would I write this so that it extracts, for example:

Page COVERSPLIT + all the subsequent pages *without* a barcode until it gets to the next page *with* a barcode (COMPLAINTSPLIT, for example)?
​
And also, how could I do this so that it extracts the page with barcode COVERSPLIT with its pages (until it reaches the next barcode) but keeping all those pages together in one pdf?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have already noticed that you have a lot of repeated code. What you can do in that case is put the small part which varies between the otherwise-identical code into a variable.

So, if we get a list of the barcodes which identify the type of a page we can iterate over them to find out what type the current page is. If there is no barcode then we assume the page type is unchanged from the previous page.

```
Option Infer On
Option Strict On

Imports System.IO

Module Module1

    Class PageType
        Property Identifier As String
        Property TypeName As String
    End Class

    Sub Main()
        Dim dir = "G:\Word\Department Folders\Pre-Suit\Drafts-IL\2-IL_AttyReview\2018-09\Reviewed\"

        Dim inputFile = Path.Combine(dir, "ZTEST01.SMITH.pdf")
        Dim unmerged = Path.Combine(dir, "unmerged")

        ' Set up a list of the identifiers to be searched for and the corresponding names to be used in the filename.
        Dim pageTypes As New List(Of PageType)
        Dim ids = {"COVERSPLIT", "COMPLAINTSPLIT", "EXHIBITSPLIT", "MILSPLIT", "SUMSPLIT"}
        Dim nams = {" Cover Sheet ", " Complaint ", " Exhibit ", " Military ", " Summons "}
        For i = 0 To ids.Length - 1
            pageTypes.Add(New PageType With {.Identifier = ids(i), .TypeName = nams(i)})
        Next

        Dim extracted = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(inputFile).Substring(0, 7)

        Dim extractor As New TextExtractor()

        ' Load sample PDF document
        extractor.LoadDocumentFromFile(inputFile)

        Dim pageCount = extractor.GetPageCount()
        Dim currentPageTypeName = "UNKNOWN"

        ' Search each page for a keyword 
        For i = 0 To pageCount - 1

            ' Find the type of the current page
            ' If it is not present on the page, then the last one found will be used.
            For Each pt In pageTypes
                If extractor.Find(i, pt.Identifier, False) Then
                    currentPageTypeName = pt.TypeName
                End If
            Next

            ' Extract page
            Using splitter As New DocumentSplitter() With {.OptimizeSplittedDocuments = True}
                Dim pageNumber = i + 1  ' (!) page number in ExtractPage() is 1-based
                Dim outputfile = Path.Combine(unmerged, extracted & currentPageTypeName & pageNumber & ".pdf")

                splitter.ExtractPage(inputFile, outputfile, pageNumber)

                Console.WriteLine("Extracted page " & pageNumber & " to file """ & outputfile & """")

            End Using

        Next

        extractor.Dispose()

        Console.WriteLine()
        Console.WriteLine("Press any key...")
        Console.ReadKey()

    End Sub

End Module
```

I *suspect* that the `Using splitter As New DocumentSplitter() With {.OptimizeSplittedDocuments = True}` should be *outside* the For loop so that it is not created and destroyed for every page.

I renamed your `page` variable as it interfered with the concise use of IO.Path. It's better to use the Path.Combine method to combine parts of a path because it takes care of the path separator characters for you.

---

To accumulate all the pages of a type into one file, you would have to detect when the type changes and then use [ExtractPageRange](https://cdn.bytescout.com/help/BytescoutPDFExtractorSDK/html/d8c7eacb-940b-69bd-1db7-34e304a4e1ce.htm) method. I don't have Bytescout.PDFExtractor or the example PDF, so I can't try it out.